# Custom SOQL query for time-based workflow queue

Tags: apex, soql, workflow

I have a client that wants to create a custom report that shows the scheduled time based workflow queue.  We are aware of the Time-Based workflow Monitor but we need to see more information than what is provided in the monitor.

Is it possible to query the time-based workflow queue directly via custom apex classes?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way I believe you can do this with apex and soql.

One paid add on your client can add is [Event log](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.196.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_eventlogfile.htm) .With Event logs enabled you will can write some REST API or run third party analytics tools or use apex also(there may be some limitations with apex) to get info around time based workflows .You can also design to get near real time updates